# Installing kubuntu using a pendrive!

Tags: kubuntu, installation

I am a newbie in Kubuntu/Linux but i know the basics, so i have an old Kubuntu 9.10 version CD, which runs fine when i go live (ie. live CD). However i installed Kubuntu onto my pendrive to make it a bootable one, it was successful as the installation finished successfully. However when i tried to boot using my pen drive, kubuntu is recognised but i get a console (similar to DOS) rather than any GUI that we usually get. I guess thats the GRUB console, it supports certain commands like ls (which gives 7 HD0,1 2 3 etc. like o/p) halt (shut down) and exit (gets hanged!)
So please tell me what to do, i tried out all commands in the help section! But i didnt get directed to the customary GUI of kubuntu, is my PD not installed properly or any other reason, i tried it a hundred times and over!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [usb-creator](https://launchpad.net/usb-creator) to install Kubuntu in to your USB disk. I think it's the best way of installing any Ubuntu version in to a USB disk. Format the USB drive and try installing Kubuntu again using usb-creator. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) document contains in-depth information on how to do that.